# Autocomplete first line shouldn't be active

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I'm still working on autocomplete integration and found out strange behaviour. When I start to type something and autocomplete popup is shown, I can't move to the next line with 'Enter' because first line in autocomplete is always active. How can I disable this?

Here's how it looks: [image]

I just want to leave 'ace' word on the fifth line and go to the 6th line with 'enter' but can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've changed in ext-language_tools.js:

Changed to false

```
this.autoSelect = false; // changed from true

popup.setData = function(list) {
    popup.setValue(lang.stringRepeat("\n", list.length), -1);
    popup.data = list || [];
    popup.setRow(-1); // changed from 0
};
```

And added additional condition:

```
popup.setRow = function (line) {
    if (line == -1) // added
    {
        popup.selection.clearSelection();
        selectionMarker.start.row = selectionMarker.end.row = line;
        popup.session._emit("changeBackMarker");
        popup.moveCursorTo(line, 0);
        if (popup.isOpen)
            popup._signal("select");
    } else {
        line = Math.max(0, Math.min(this.data.length, line));
        if (selectionMarker.start.row != line) {
            popup.selection.clearSelection();
            selectionMarker.start.row = selectionMarker.end.row = line || 0;
            popup.session._emit("changeBackMarker");
            popup.moveCursorTo(line || 0, 0);
            if (popup.isOpen)
                popup._signal("select");
        }
    };
};
```